# Sorting of List with user defined key returning None

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting, tuples

I am trying to sort a list of tuples.

```
tuples.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[-1])
```

I am calling the function

```
def sort_last(tuples):
```

like

```
sort_last([(1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 1)])
```

or

```
sort_last([(2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 1)])
```

but the `return tuples` is giving me `NONE` always
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `.sort` sorts *in-place* and returns `None`. If you check `tuples` after you've called your function, you'll find that `tuples` is sorted...

Comment: @JonClements but he says he is 'return'ing tuples.

Comment: @theharshest good point but it doesn't look like the OP is... difficult to tell without the actual body of the function though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> def sort_last(tuples=None):
...     tuples.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[-1])
...     return tuples

>>> sort_last([(2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3)])
[(2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3)]

sort(...)
    L.sort(cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) -- stable sort *IN PLACE*;
    cmp(x, y) -> -1, 0, 1
```

So List sort methods returns None and sorts the `original` List itself.

You can use `sorted` method which returns sorted new list without `changing` the original list.

```
sorted(...)
    sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) --> new sorted list

>>> def sort_last(tuples):
...     return sorted(tuples, key=lambda tup: tup[-1])
... 
>>> sort_last([(2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3)])
[(2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`list.sort` return `None` `list.sort` is an expression not a function when you `print` `list.sort` it return `None` and `list` is mutable hence changes are seen in `list`.

```
In [200]: l =  [(2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3)]

In [201]: l.sort(key=lambda t: t[-1])

In [202]: l
Out[202]: [(2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3)]

In [205]: print l.sort(key=lambda t: t[-1])
None
```

Try `sorted`:-

```
In [209]: a = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[-1]) # retrun sorted sequence

In [210]: a
Out[210]: [(2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3)]


In [211]: a = l.sort(key=lambda t: t[-1]) # list.sort return None 

In [212]: a
```

Answer (score 1):

using sorted:

```
 >>> sorted([(1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 1)], key=lambda x:x[0])
 [(1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 2)]
 >>> sorted([(1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 1)], key=lambda x:x[1])
 [(2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3)]
 >>>
```

Answer (score 0):

sems you use `tuples` as `list` object.

[`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) will sort list itself, it will not return sorted list.

I you want sorted list then use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)